# Revert Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

By using SSMS, I altered a stored procedure but have no backup. I already closed all files and they were not saved.

But I need it's revert. How can I revert it?

Comment: Its not possible.

Comment: it is not saved anywhere except your database.

Comment: @DarkRob, not saved

Comment: I mean your procedure definition is saved in database only, if you alter it and there is no backup, then you cannot recover it again from anywhere.

Comment: if you have worked on same procedure in recent times then you may check your `temp` directory in case of `windows`. There you find some `sql` files. Try to open and check them, might be you find somewhere.

Comment: already check and then I ask in Stackoverflow

Comment: there might be a chance to restore it from a database backup.

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim, adding to the comment from iSR5, you can restore a database backup (with a different name if on the same server) and then script the proc. Consider using source control going forward for this reason and many others.